# Singular points and tangent lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Find the singular points and the corresponding tangent lines of $X^4+Y^4-X^2Y^2$.

I get that the singular points are those of the form $(a,a)$ and $(a,-a)$. The corresponding tangent lines are $X=-a, Y=-a$ and $X=-a, Y=a$ respectively. Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you write is not correct.
Let $\omega $ be  is a primitive third root of $1$. 
We then have  $$X^4-X^2Y^2+Y^4=(Y-i\omega X)(Y+i\omega X)(Y-i\omega^2 X)(Y+i\omega^2 X)$$ so that your affine curve is a cone, the union of the 4 lines $$y= i\omega x,\: y=-i\omega x,\: y=i\omega^2x, \:y=-i\omega^2x$$ The only singularity is   at the origin $(0,0)$ and the tangent lines at the origin are the very same four lines described above, i.e. the irreducible components of the curve.

I have assumed  up to now that the base field is algebraically closed and of  characteristic $\neq 3, 2$.
 If the characteristic *is* $3$, the curve has equation $x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2)^2=0$ and is singular everywhere.
The tangent lines  at the origin are the two double lines $(y-ix)^2=0, (y+ix)^2=0$ (where, of course,  $i$ is a root in the base field of $z^2+1=0$).
At the other points of the curve the tangent lines consist of the line on which the point lies counted with multiplicity $2$.
Similarly, if the characteristic is $2$,  the curve has equation $x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2+xy)^2=0$ and is singular everywhere.

Comment: I don't understand. Singular points are where both partial derivatives are zero. In this case both partial derivatives are zero when $X=Y$ so why is the only singular point (0,0)? Thanks

Comment: No: both  partial derivatives are non-zero  for $x=y\neq0$ (in char. $\neq 2,3$) .  If you don't agree, post your calculations.

Comment: @GGeorges Elencwajg Sorry you are correct

Comment: Doesn't the union of the four lines you mention actually correspond to the curve defined by the polynomial $x^4 + y^4 +x^2 y^2$?

Comment: Why? That’s not  he curve OP asked about?

Comment: @PrinceM: Sorry, you are right. I had forgotten to add a factor $i$ . Corrected. And thanks for your attention.

Comment: It might even be useful to show how the change of variable y —> iy carries the answer to the correct curve

Comment: Users:  Let me emphasize that my answer is now (hopefully) correct and that there is no need at all to mention @user Prince M's curve.