# Definition of Tangent line at singular point ? and geometric meaning

Tags: algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the book Complex algebraic curves by Kirwan. In the exercise of chapter 2 of the book i am asked to find the tangent line at a singular point.

I was able to calculate the singular point.
I want a definition of tangent line, so that i can calculate the same? 
what is the geometric meaning of a tangent line here? Is it related in any way to theory of smooth manifolds?

Can someone please explain with minimal use of new math. Thank you!

Comment: $x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2+x^2y^2=(x^2-y^2)^2-(ixy)^2=(x^2-y^2+ixy)(x^2-y^2-ixy)$ Now factor each of those using the quadratic formula. You can see that your curve is a bunch of straight lines.

Comment: By the way, your question was asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/784095/744042) before.

Comment: no, i want definition of tangent line, and what is the geometric meaning of it.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+y^4-x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-3x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2+\sqrt3xy)(x^2+y^2-\sqrt3xy)$$
 which you can further factor as four lines, which are their own tangents.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^2$, not just the origin.

Comment: @OscarRascal: ooops, I didn't see "Complex".

Comment: but what do you mean by tangent line?